# bootstrap navbar nav-pills vertical @ 768px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar with a series of links displayed as nav-pills.

The pills display horizontally on mobile correctly however when the screen gets to above 768px they swap to a vertical layout which I do not want.

I suspect there is a media query somewhere that triggers @ 768px however I am unsure of where.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Title -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <!-- Required bootstrap placeholder for the collapsed menu -->

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown 
                <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href=""><i class="icon-home icon-2x"></i> Home<br></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href=""><i class=" icon-pencil icon-2x"></i>About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href=""><i class=" icon-briefcase icon-2x"></i>Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href=""><i class=" icon-envelope icon-2x"></i>Contact Us</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

          <li>
            <%= link_to search_path do %>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i><!-- Find -->
            <% end %>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#" class="visible-xs visible-sm" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#activity_parent">
              <i class="fa fa-list"></i> 
            </a>
          </li>                   
      </ul> 

    </div>

  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**Edit**
Ok, I found the following bootstrap media queries:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
}
```

I have changed the navbar menu items to "nav navbar-nav" from "nav nav-pills" and added the following css so that these setting remain even when the screen is less than 768px.

```
.navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
}
```

Now the links are displayed horizontally regardless of screen size. I do now have a new related problem.

When the screen > 768px the dropdown looks correct:

[image]

When the screen < 768px the dropdown looks incorrect:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the link of the page which having the issue or the updated the code codepen and share the link !!!

Comment: Not live yet, just development. Have added code.

Comment: Please create a repro since I can't seem to reproduce your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38305/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this may helps you.

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .nav-pills>li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

**For Demo**

Here is the [codepen demo link.](https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/mBjaeO)